# Dependency Cycles with TYPO3 Crawler and TYPO3 10.2

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

The TYPO3v9 branch of the crawler, should work (at least most of it) with TYPO3 10.2 as well. But I have gotten a bug report on cycle dependencies, not from composer but from the classloading after the extension is activated.

```
Your dependencies have cycles. That will not work out. Cycles found: 

aoe/crawler/initialization->typo3/cms-frontend/authentication,
aoe/crawler/initialization->typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe,
typo3/cms-core/normalized-params-attribute->typo3/cms-frontend/timetracker,
typo3/cms-frontend/authentication->typo3/cms-frontend/backend-user-authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/authentication->typo3/cms-frontend/maintenance-mode,
typo3/cms-frontend/authentication->typo3/cms-frontend/site,
typo3/cms-frontend/backend-user-authentication->typo3/cms-frontend/site,
typo3/cms-frontend/base-redirect-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/site-resolver,
typo3/cms-frontend/eid->typo3/cms-core/normalized-params-attribute,
typo3/cms-frontend/maintenance-mode->typo3/cms-core/normalized-params-attribute,
typo3/cms-frontend/maintenance-mode->typo3/cms-frontend/eid,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-argument-validator->typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver->aoe/crawler/initialization,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/backend-user-authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/site,
typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/static-route-resolver,
typo3/cms-frontend/preview-simulator->typo3/cms-frontend/authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/preview-simulator->typo3/cms-frontend/backend-user-authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/site->typo3/cms-core/normalized-params-attribute,
typo3/cms-frontend/static-route-resolver->typo3/cms-frontend/base-redirect-resolver,
typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe->typo3/cms-frontend/authentication,
typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe->typo3/cms-frontend/eid,
typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe->typo3/cms-frontend/page-argument-validator,
typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe->typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver,
typo3/cms-frontend/tsfe->typo3/cms-frontend/preview-simulator
```

I’m not really sure how to deal with this. Any suggestions.

Here is the `composer.json` in case you need it

```
{
    "name": "tnm/typo3v10-test",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "",
    "require": {
        "typo3/minimal": "^10.2",
        "typo3/cms-introduction": "~4.0",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^10.2",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^10.2",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.2",
        "bk2k/bootstrap-package": "*",
        "aoepeople/crawler": "dev-typo3v9"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor",
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
            "web-dir": "public"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot I had this question still open, but have a solution for it.

This was due to wrong middleware registration

```
Separate middleware initialization (#527)

The frontend usergroup needs to be set before the typo3/cms-frontend/page-resolver is processed. At that time the TSFE controller isn't initialized yet, so the TSFE configuration needs to be done at a later point.
```

https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/commit/b5443c33c635958635009c4d36ba30f5d97bebd0